# how to show the content of c++ vector in VSCode during debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

[image]

I'm using visual studio code to debug a c++ file. I need to see the content of vector h during the debugging.

I'm searching for a lot of solutions and no one worked for me.

How can I see the content of h in variables?

Comment: Generally, I 'd only use Visual Studio to debug C++. Apart from that, you may mouseover the variable and see what happens.

Comment: I'm using VSCode since it has a small size in comparison with Visual Studio.

Comment: From where did you install your compiler and debugger?

Comment: from here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

Comment: Then you won't go far with mingw. Proper debugging needs proper tools. When it comes to debugging, VS has no match.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll use VS for that.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis The whole Linux world lives with GCC & GDB, and I assure you there's a way to set up pretty-printing with them.

Comment: @MuhammadAlbrham The plain MinGW isn't very good, get MinGW-w64. I recommend installing it from MSYS2, since they ship an up-to-date version. Then pretty-printing vectors should either work out of the box, OR after running a single command in the debugger console: `python register_libstdcxx_printers(None)`. Since you're using Microsoft's extension for C++ debugging, you might need to prepend `-exec ` to the command.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this is Windows and 2021; Console pretty-printing is something Windows developers have forgotten long time ago.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I can't argue with VS having one of the most convenient debugger GUIs. Just saying that MinGW is *viable*. There are GUIs for GDB, even though I don't have much experience with them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, can you provide me with the downloaded link for it?

Comment: @Pain Link for what?